# Mac OSX Cocoa App: Is it possible to allow your App to use the san francisco font (one used for Apple Watch)?

Tags: macos, cocoa, fonts, nsfont

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_(2014_typeface)

I want to use this font for my Mac OSX App. However, I am not sure if it is possible currently. It is said that by OSX 10.11 that the default font will be replaced by the San Francisco font. If this is possible, how do I go about this? Any tips or suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It is always recommended to use the system font. All the standard Cocoa controls use them. This means that, if the system font changes, all controls and textFields use the new system font automatically. So there is nothing for you to do.

If you set up a `NSFont` object manually, I recommend you to use `systemFontOfSize:`. This will give you Helvetica Neue under Yosemite and San Francisco under El Capitan.

You can download the San Francisco font [here](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/), but I am not sure if you are allowed to use it in your app. I think it is for private use only.

**Update:**

Apple has switched to San Francisco font on macOS some time ago. so this problem does not longer exist.